# How can I get windows to boot again?

Tags: boot, windows

I have been trying to find a solution to this for a long time now and I'm desperate because I am starting college online in a couple of weeks and need to use windows for a specific application called "Bookshelf". But anyways, I installed Ubuntu on my computer years ago and I used to be able to boot into either one at startup. But eventually I started having problems where I couldn't get Windows to boot anymore. I would uninstall the latest windows updates from the Windows recovery center and it would work for a time but now that won't work anymore either. To be honest I didn't exactly know what I was doing when I set it all up and at this point reading forum posts trying to troubleshoot this just keeps giving me answers that I can't even comprehend without prerequisite knowledge that I apparently don't have. I just want to get back to where I could boot either OS from startup. I don't want to get rid of Ubuntu either. Please for the love of God can someone explain this to me in simple terms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: If your system is UEFI, you should always be able to boot Windows from the EFI menu (some key at power-up to allow you to select device or Os to boot). Choose Windows, and it should boot -- no grub involved. If it doesn't boot, that's a Windows problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago, I faced a similar issue. I fixed it using [this](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) tool called Rescatux. It is a special OS that can fix issues related to the bootloader and some other stuff and can be run directly through a flash USB.

To fix this you need to have a flash USB of size 2GB or more.

If you have another pc with windows running on it, make sure to install Rufus v.3.08 and the Rescatux ISO, and flash it with MBR and DD settings into your flash USB.

If you don't have another pc lying around, don't worry. Use [Balena Etcher](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-balenaetcher-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) and flash into your memory stick the ISO of rescatux.

And make sure to follow the official Recatux tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As a technician, I would advise you to backup all your user data, bookmarks, pictures, anything you want to keep to external hard drive or 2 USB's for safety and start over. Repairing a broken multi boot system you have been managing for extended periods of time have complicated issues resulting from updates, installing programs and data corruption from failed updates or installs of software that caused registry compatibility issues. Starting over after a dual verified backup works 100% of the time to get your multi boot system working. I would install the latest windows, get it updated and working, then install the latest Ubuntu from a bootable USB creating a multiboot system. If you have a computer with 2 hard drives and install your operating systems on a separate physical hard drive, you can specify in BIOS which hard drive to boot to, Windows or Linux should your multi-boot loader fail.